# mathematically represention

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I want to mathematically formulate how the set B⊆A is shown. So that summation of elements of B would be smaller or equal to quantity (bound to) 'q' providing that the maximum number of elements of A are chosen.
for example:

```
A = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
q = 11
then because the maximum elements equal 4 then B = {1,2,3,4} or {1,2,3,5}.
```

Comment: Incomprehensible.

Comment: Your question is incomprehensible. You never tell us that you consider sets of natural numbers. It is not clear what you assume and what you want to prove. Moreover, it is always the case that the sum of the elements in a set of natural numbers is “some quantity”. But that is not very interesting.

Are you asking if one can always, given some set of natural numbers $A$ and bound $k$ find a subset $B \subseteq A$ such that the sum of the elements in $B$ is exactly $k$? Clearly the answer to this is no.

Please read your question before you post it. Will it make sense to other people?

Comment: I made some correction to my answer. please look at again. Disregarding the type of elements, I want to show the mathematical representation of that not proving any thing.

Comment: Does $A$ always consist of consecutive integers starting at $1$? What do you mean by "*providing that the maximum elements of A are chosen*", and how does that relate to the given example?

Comment: 1- No, A is not always consecutive integers. it was an example.

Comment: 2- providing that means: the summation is acceptable if there is no other subset like B' that that |B| < |B'| (|B| is the number of elements in B) .

Comment: You have to define a "measure" $\mu_B$ for a **finite** set $B$ of numbers such tat $\mu_B$ is the sum of the (numbers that are) elements of $B$. Thus, with e.g. $B = \{ 1,2,3 \}$, $\mu_B=6$.

Comment: @mauro-allegranza Thank you. But what i want is how to represent the mathematical formulation not how to solve it. For example **`B={all Ai | max⁡(∑(A_i/A_i))}`**. This formulation is true or not?

Comment: still trying to understand this ... Is it the maximum *number* of elements? In this case, you can get 4 elements whose sum does not exceed $q$, But you can't get 5 elements. So, $\{ 1,2,3,4\}$ is an acceptable $B$, but any set with less or more than 4 elements would not? And any set whose elements sum up to more than $q$ would not be acceptable. Would $\{ 1,2,3,5 \}$ be an acceptable $B$?

Comment: @mauro-allegranza  @ Bram28  You are true, B= {1,2,3,5} , is acceptable too, because we could not find any other set that have more than 4 elements so that the summation of its elements is equal or less than  q=11.But there is no difference between B1= {1,2,3,4}, B2= {1,2,3,5} because i want to maximize the number of elements (i.e. 4) bounding their summation to q, nothing else matter.

Comment: Still incomprehensible.

Comment: @mauro-allegranza @ Bram28 in **{${B∈P(A)∣μB=11}$}** I want to show the mathematical formulation of {${μB}$}

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA dear freind I think this there is misunderstanding, as I told you the bound is of the second importance, and the maximum number of subset B∈P(A) is the answer I am looking for. {B∈P(A)∣μB=Σi(i∈B)<=11} will result ∅,{1},{2},… that is not the true. The only B= {1,2,3,4} or {1,2,3,5} is true that have the maximum number of elements in P(A). I could not find the maximization in your comment.

Comment: By your description we can also have B = {1} {2}, {3}...{9},{1,2}....{1,9},{2,3}....{2,9},{3,4}...{3,8}{4,5}{4,6}{4,7}{5,6},{1,2,3}...{1,2,8},{1,3,4}...{1,3,7},{1,4,5},{1,4,6},{2,3,4}...{2,3,6},{2,4,5}.

Comment: @fleablood I am pretty sure that the OP only wants the sets with the maximal number of elements. So, in his example, $\{ 1,2,3,4 \}$ and $\{ 1,2,3,5 \}$ are acceptable, but no other sets.  This idea is what I formalized in my answer below.

Comment: You are probably right, but I am pointing out a lack of clarity in the question.  And the op did say "maximal"; not "precise size.  There are 4 potentially similar but different questions that could be asked depending on whether the maximal elements must be exact or maximal, and whether the sum must be exact or maximal.  All 4 are worth exploring, I think.

Comment: Ah, I see in a comment I overlooked that the op meant the set must have precisely the maximal.  To which I have to point out "maximal" is the wrong choice of wrd.  "Cardinality" would have been both clearer and more accurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so B is an acceptable set relative to A and q iff:

$$B \in P(A) \land \mu_{B} \leq q \: \land \neg \exists B' (B' \in P(A) \land \mu_{B'} \leq q) \land |B| < |B'|)$$

where

$$\mu_{B} = \sum\nolimits_{i \in B} i$$